# convert uploaded file to bitmap image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload, bitmap

I have a `FileUpload` box and `button`. In my scenario the files that are going to be uploaded are image files. I want to convert these image files into bitmaps and store them temporarily in a buffer.

I have a function which takes two bitmap inputs and tells us whether the two files match or not.

One of the file will come from the `FileUpload` control on `ButtonClick` event and the other bitmap will be read from Database.

Can anyone tell me as to how do I convert these files to bitmaps and pass both the bitmap objects to the function.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Starting it from scratch. the idea is what i have mentioned above but aint able to figure out as to how do i go for it. Can you just post a generalized code accomplish the task or any direction would also suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a  bitmap of your uploaded image as follows:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpPostedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(userFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

You then get the stored copy (which hopefully is stored as a byte array and you have an ID to get it), and then convert it to bitmap as follows

```
byte[] byteArrayStoredImage = ImageService.GetImageData(imageID);
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayStoredImage);
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpStoredImage = new Bitmap(imgStream);
```

With the two bitmaps in hand (bmpPostedImage and bmpStoredImage), you can then call the function to do the comparison. For a start you can try this function from http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2859.htm and see how it it goes.  there may be more efficient functions out there to do the comparison, trying out a google search for that will be a goo thing to try.

EDIT

Find below the code to retrieve image from the database with the assumptions I put in the comment below:

```
    public byte[] GetImageData(string imageID)
    {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstringname"];
        SqlConnection connection = SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select imgfile from myimages where imgname=@imageId", connection);
        SqlParameter myparam = command1.Parameters.Add("@imageId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
        myparam.Value = imageID;
        byte[] img = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
        return img;
    }
```

and then change ImageService.GetImageData(imageID) to GetImageData(imageID);

Note also, that error handling is not addressed here, so might have to factor that into your final code.

Comment: `ImageService.GetImageData()` does not exist. What should I do. I have stored the image in `image` datatype in the database.

Comment: @Piyush: Of course ImageService.GetImageData(imageID) will have to be replaced by your own code that you use to connect to your database to retrieve the image, but which returns a byte array of the image data.

Comment: can you help me with retrieving an image stored in database as an `image` datatype and converting it into `byte[]` array.

Comment: I am trying to use `ToArray()` but this is not working for me.

Comment: @Piyush: I assume you are familiar with ADO.NET, and that you are using SQL Server. The sample code from here (http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Save-Read-Image-Database.aspx) will put you on the right track. I will edit my answer to put short and direct way to accomplish this however.

Comment: I am using `var image = (from c in db.Citizen_tables
                     select c.FingerPrint).ToList();` code to get all the fingerprint images and now querying through the resultset and converting each element into `byte[]` by the following code `byte[] arr = image.ElementAt(i).ToArray();` where `i` is a looping variable.

Comment: @Piyush: this is another dimension, One, I didn't realise you are using EF and secondly, trying to pull all images in the database to memory and then work through them will be inefficient. Concerning the code you posted, to access each image item use byte[] arr = image[i];